# Optimal way to split huge file

Tags: regex, perl, file, unix, csplit

I am trying to split a huge text file (~500 million lines of text) which is pretty regular and looks like this:

```
-- Start ---

blah blah

-- End --

-- Start --

blah blah

-- End --

...
```

where ... implies a repeating pattern and "blah blah" is of variable length ~ 2000 lines. I want to split off the first

```
-- Start --

blah blah

-- End --
```

block into a separate file and delete it from the original file in the FASTEST (runtime, given I will run this MANY times) possible way.

**The ideal solution would cut the initial block from the original file and paste it into the new file without loading the tail of the huge initial file.**

I attempted csplit in the following way:

```
csplit file.txt /End/+1
```

which is a valid way of doing this, but not very efficient in time.

EDIT: Is there a solution if we remove the last "start-end" block from file instead of the first one?

Comment: How do you hope to improve over `csplit`? What does it do which could be left out? The main overhead is going to be I/O and there is no way you can avoid reading the entire file.

Comment: @tripleee The ideal solution would cut the initial block from the original file and paste it into the new file without loading the tail of the huge initial file. => i.e. delete the "cut" block in place. so that each time you run the script you only operate on ~2000 lines of text versus ~500 million lines.

Comment: `csplit` does no such thing (unless you give it a regex which requires significant backtracking, I suppose). It reads a line at a time and writes it out, opening a new output file whenever the context condition is fulfilled.

Comment: If you want to delete the first 2k lines from a 500M line file, you will have to write 500M-2k lines (with the number decreasing as you repeat the process) to one file each time, as well as the 2k lines to another file.  This will be painfully slow.  It would be better to use `csplit` and create all the small files at once.

Comment: If you really want the fastest way, you make a single pass over the file and start writing a new file each time you encounter "-- Start --" and close that file when you encounter "-- End --". The tradeoff is that you must use twice as much space on disk but rewriting the original file for the extraction of every block is pointless and slow.

Comment: @MarkSetchell This is something I was initially considering as well. But this solution will generate 500M/2K ~= 250000 files, which is pointless and pretty disgusting. Please see one of the responses below for an efficient implementation of what I was asking for.

Comment: I would choose 250,000 files over re-writing a 500M (but decreasing) line file 250,000 times which is also pretty pointless :-) Storage is cheap - a 3TB costs less than the consulting hours we have collectively put into this question :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the beginning removed from the original file, you have no choice but to read and write the whole rest of the file. To remove the end (as you suggest in your edit) it can be much more efficient:

```
use File::ReadBackwards;
use File::Slurp 'write_file';
my $fh = File::ReadBackwards->new( 'inputfile', "-- End --\n" )
    or die "couldn't read inputfile: $!\n";
my $last_chunk = $fh->readline
    or die "file was empty\n";
my $position = $fh->tell;
$fh->close;
truncate( 'inputfile', $position );
write_file( 'lastchunk', $last_chunk );
```

Comment: This looks good actually. Just to make sure, can we confidently state that this will only iterate over ~2000 lines of text (roughly one block size) and not the rest of the file?

Comment: Yes, it only will read the very end of the file (though it reads in blocks of up to 8k at a time)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like the following will help you:

Split the file after every `-- End --` marker.  Create new files with a simple incremented suffix.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = shift;

my $i = 0;
my $fh;

open my $infh, '<', $file;

while (<$infh>) {
    open $fh, '>', $file . '.' . ++$i if !$fh;
    print $fh $_;
    undef $fh if /^-- END --/;
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no [`truncate`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html) equivalent for removing data from the beginning of a file.

If you really wanted to do this in stages, then I would suggest that you simply [`tell`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html) the last place you read from, so you can [`seek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) when you're ready to output another file.

Comment: I don't fully understand your code, but I'm guessing it doesn't delete the block from the initial file? Also, is there a fast solution if you consume the last "start-end" block from the file?

Comment: To get the last one you could work with seek from the end of the file and then read blocks of fixed size and look for the pattern until it is found. And because the pattern could be at the border of two of these blocks there need to be overlap. Exact details would depend on the maximum size of the string to match (e.g. how big the overlap would need to be) and how much data are usually expected between start and end to get the optimal block size.

Comment: To get the last one it would also be possible to use [`File::ReadBackwards`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::ReadBackwards).  I don't know how efficient it would be, but it could work.

Comment: File::ReadBackwards is plenty efficient for this purpose; you could hand-write code that might be faster at the cost of probably introducing bugs.

Comment: @Miller's suggestion of not actually updating the big file, just (somewhere) storing how much of it you have already read and seeking there next time is a very good one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`flip-flop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) Operator to get the content between this Pattern:

```
use File::Slurp;
my @text = read_file( 'filename' ) ;
foreach my $line (@text){
  if ($line =~ /Start/ .. /End/) {
    # do stuff with $line
    print $line; # or so
  }
}
```

When your file is large, be carefull with slurping the whole file at once!

Comment: “When your file is large, be careful” – the given file here has ~500 million lines. That's half a GB in newlines only, and would probably total at above 5GB. Anyway, a good point about the flip-flop operator, it might come in handy here.

Comment: @amon Yes, I estimate the file to be around 54GB. How does this perform in that context? This looks like it only finds and prints the wanted block, but does not delete it in place?